# Charset in Phonegap sqlite for Asian characters

Tags: javascript, sqlite, utf-8, cordova, character-encoding

I wrote a simple phonegap app that people can add contents to local sqlite database. This works fine with my devices, but some reported that the Chinese characters are garbled and just don't show correctly. I presume it is the charset issue for sqlite in phonegap storage, right? How can I make sure all the charset settings to be utf8 (I set the meta of my html files to be utf8 of course).

Comment: More details required? What's the sqlite schema, what's the html, and what's the access layer for talking to sqlite? Any of those can cause an encoding mismatch when moving text from "user input" to "database"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that I use css "font-family: XXX" where "XXX" is an Asian font, and phonegap apps won't correctly load non-English fonts now...